# Some options on DirectX control panel was disabled on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, directx, directx-9

I am using DirectX 9.0 on Windows 8, when I open the DirectX control panel, I found some options was disabled, I am running as a administrator, so this is not an privilege issue. why this happened? I can't turn on the debug version runtime since it is disabled. see picture below. the SDK I am using is June 2010

[image]

Comment: This is the intended behaviour on Windows 8. Use the Visual Studio 2012 graphics debugger for debugging.

Comment: @Nico Schertler, I try to launch the graphics debugger from VS 2012, but it only has the options for DX10/11, no options for DirectX 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Microsoft XNA forum

The Direct3D 9 Developer Runtime (aka D3D9D.DLL) in the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) is not compatible with Windows 8. In fact, the entire Developer Runtime in the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) is not compatible with Windows 8 or with Windows 7 SP1 with KB 2370838 installed. The only way to obtain the Direct3D 9 Developer Runtime for Windows 8 is to install a 'checked' version of Windows 8.  The Direct3D 10.x/11.x Developer Runtime for Windows 8 is installed by the Windows 8.0 SDK, VS 2012, or the VS 2012 Remote Debugging Tools packages.

See [Where is the DirectX SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx)?, [Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx)?, and [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/14/directx-11-1-and-windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/directxdev/auAMrQs1SuI) is this:
Using regedit, go to key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D. The "Trusted Installer" has ownership of this key. Change ownership to Administrators, then grant "Full Access" to the Administrators (write access to values should be enough, but I didn't test this). Now run the DX Control Panel (as admin, of course). Now the changes should be saved.

Comment: good! but I still cannot modify the values in DX control panel.

Comment: What I forget to mention is that I tested this on Win 7 SP1. Sorry if this doesn't work on Win 8. Maybe you can set the registry values manually to 1: "Use Debug Version" = LoadDebugRuntime; "Enable Shader Debugging" = EnableDebugging; "Maximum Validation" = FullDebug.