# How to make my application load the right d3d9* dll

Tags: visual-studio, dll, directx, directx-9

I've installed the June 2010 Direct X SDK and written a simple DX application.

I've set the right header include and library include paths, i.e., they point to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86
```

Everything builds fine, but when I run the application, I noticed that the d3d* modules being loaded are `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll` & `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dx9d_43.dll`

I was under the assumption that linking with libs in the DirectX SDK directory will ensure that the dlls in the SDK, i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Developer Runtime\x86`
would be loaded.

I'm not sure if its related to this, but my application ends up getting a `NULL` device handle.
How can I ensure the right DLLs are loaded?

Comment: `NULL` device error can be completely irrelevant to runtime used. If you will not succeed with enabling debug runtime and will be unable to debug this yourself, post another question on StackOverflow including relevant code and what you have tried to solve it, so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `DXSDK_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)` to environment
2. Add both `"%DXSDK_DIR%\Developer Runtime\x86"` and `"%DXSDK_DIR%\Developer Runtime\x64"` to system `PATH` variable.
3. Use *DirectX Control Panel* (`%DXSDK_DIR%\Utilities\bin\x86\dxcpl.exe` and `%DXSDK_DIR%\Utilities\bin\x64\dxcpl.exe`) to enable debug runtime
4. `#define D3D_DEBUG_INFO` in your code before DirectX includes
5. If you're on Windows that is newer that Windows 7, you'll be unable to switch to debug runtime in *DirectX Control Panel*. You can try to set registry flags manually there: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D` and there `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D`. But most likely it will not work (on Windows that is newer that Windows 7), because DirectX 9 was deprecated a while ago, and recently some updates broke all the old stuff (even good ol' PIX). I've heard of one more option: use checked version of Windows, but didn't tried it.

Good luck with it!

References:

- [Internal Deployment of the Debug DirectX Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#internal_deployment_of_the_debug_directx_runtime)
- [Can't get debug spew for Direct3D9](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24541)
- [Some options on DirectX control panel was disabled on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772123)
- [Can't use debug version of Direct3D](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/514529-cant-use-debug-version-of-direct3d/)
- [Direct3D Programming Tip #5: Use The Debug Runtime](http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/direct3d-programming-tip-5-use-the-debug-runtime/)

Answer (score 1):

About System32 and SysWOW64

**The 'System32' folder is for 64-bit files and the 'SysWOW64' folder is for 32-bit files**

it sounds confused, especially for the folder name, this is due to the backward comparability. please read [The 'Program Files (x86)' and 'SysWOW64' folders explained](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm) for details.

So the fact is that you are building a 32 bit DirectX app on a 64 bit Windows. it will use the 32bit dlls from SysWOW64.

> I'm not sure if its related to this, but my application ends up
>   getting a NULL device handle

I am sure this is nothing related to the dll bits, you should check the return value of CreateDevice function to see what happened.

> How to make my application load the right dll?

I don't think you need to do that yourself, the system will handle that for you most of the case, if you really want to do it yourself, take a look at [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Related posts on SO

- [Why do 64-bit DLLs go to System32 and 32-bit DLLs to SysWoW64 on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows)
- [How can I test a Windows DLL file to determine if it is 32 bit or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495244/how-can-i-test-a-windows-dll-to-determine-if-it-is-32bit-or-64bit)